# Groupby pandas by specific formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

Please help me, how to use pandas groupby with some column for sum, and some column for average for example. I have a dataframe called "market":

```
product quantity    sell_price  profit
0   bread   2   5   10
1   bread   3   4   12
2   bread   1   3   3
3   milk    3   2   6
4   milk    2   1   2
```

Reproducible example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'product': ['bread', 'bread', 'bread', 'milk', 'milk'], 
                   'quantity': [2, 3, 1,3,2],
                  'sell_price': [5,4,3,2,1],
                  'profit': [10,12,3,6,2]})
```

to table like this

```
[Product][quantity][sell_price][profit]
[bread][6][4][25]
[milk][5][1,5][8]
```

where sell_price is average from each products,
quantity is sum from each products, and
profit is sum from each products

What I already did

```
market.groupby('product').sum('quantity,'profit').mean('sell_price')
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby.agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html):

```
new_df = df.groupby('Product').agg({'quantity':'sum', 'profit': 'sum', 'sell_price': 'mean'})
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
         quantity  profit  sell_price
Product                              
bread           6      25         4.0
milk            5       8         1.5
```

Comment: Whooaa thank you. Next question, if I want to add some column called "ABC" which the formula: ABC= (quantity*sell_price) in each group / (sum of quantity in each group). How i do that?